# Is there any compiler flag that I could use in the code below to report a warning about UB?

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

I'm not very familiar with the GCC compiler, and I'm trying to run a code using two source files in [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WroY2XLK0PxCH5ob). Let's start with the first code using the main file (default) and a second source file named `other.cc`, as follows:

**main file**

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    int i = 1;
    static const int k = 1;
};
extern A a;    // The object a is defined in other.cc

int main() {
    std::cout << a.i << '\n';
    std::cout << a.k << '\n';
}
```

**other.cc**

```
struct A {
    int i = 1;
    static const int k = 1;
};
A a{2};
```

Note that I have to insert the name of the file `other.cc` in the box **Compiler Options**, on the left of the Wandbox, in order for this file to be compiled and linked into the final object file. Running this code I get the numbers 2 and 1 printed below, and they are correct.

```
2
1
```

Now, if I exclude the file `other.cc` from the compilation and linking processes, by deleting its name from the **Compilation options** box, I get a linking error, about the reference to the non-static data member `A::i` being used in the expression

```
std::cout << a.i << '\n';
```

If I then erase this statement from the code, it *apparently* runs normally, because the compiler replaces the variable `a.k` by its constant value 1 in the remaining statement `std::cout << a.k << '\n';` in main(), printing 1. But this is considered undefined behavior, according to [[basic.def.odr]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10) and [[intro.compliance]/2 (2.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#2.3). Note the "no diagnostic required" mentioned on [basic.def.odr]/10.

I'm trying then to force the compiler to emit an error in this case, by the use of some flag that will prevent this optimization. I have already tried with the flags `-fkeep-static-consts` and `-fno-keep-static-consts`, to no avail. Is there any other flag that I could use to avoid this undefined behavior?

I got this example from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/zmRxdNdVUNI/Q-976qkUBgAJ) in C++ std-discussion.

**I know that by defining the object `a` in the first file would solve the problem. But that's not what I am looking for with this weird example. I'm just trying to get a better picture of how compilers work in these unusual circumstances.**

Comment: @CoryKramer: aggregate initialization.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" is a term defined by the C++ Standard to describe a sort of incorrect C++ program. It is not (usually) related to what compiler, compiler flags, etc. you use to process a program.

Comment: @CoryKramer A is an aggregate type

Comment: Mystery abbreviation ‘UB’??

Comment: @zipzit: UB stand for **U**ndefined **B**ehavior.

Comment: The compiler is *not* required to warn you about engaging in UB. It is *your* responsibility to just not do that. Sorry, but such are the rules of the language.

Comment: @zipzit - "UB" == "Undefined Behaviour".

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's what I'm trying to do. Is there a compiler  flag that would prevent this faulty optimization?

Comment: @Ayrosa huh? *What* are you trying to do? If you are trying to invoke UB then all bets are off.. please be specific, *what* are you trying to do?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think he wants the compilation to fail with an error.

Comment: @Ayrosa FWIW clang++ does the same thing

Comment: @John Perry - then we are back to the definition of UB; it may or may not fail.. you just can't tell. Just don't write UB..

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding what's being asked.  Don't _describe_ the code that you're asking about, please show that exact code.

Comment: I think the program (with one translation unit, without `a.i`) is actually ill-formed no diagnostic required, not undefined behavior.  [basic.def.odr]/10 has "shall" but never "undefined behavior".  (Though, does that difference have any consequences?)

Comment: @aschepler This code is UB. Did you look at [intro.compliance]/2 (2.3) http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#2.3 ?

Comment: @Ayrosa: That's not the same thing as "undefined behavior", strictly speaking. UB is a *runtime* property. Now, you can write code that always provokes UB. But the things the standard defines as UB are things which are properties of runtime values, not compile-time constructs. Yes, the standard does not impose any particular behavior on ill-formed programs, but that's different (technically) from declaring the construct to have UB.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm pretty sure, but I don't remember where, I read a comment by Daniel Krügler, saying this, i.e., that an ill-formed code with no diagnostic required is basically a code with undefined behavior. And AFAICT,  [intro.compliance]/2 (2.3) seems to confirm this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer to a different question would be more illuminating. The dread of undefined behavior lies in the inability to guarantee the same runtime results when using different compilers. So:

**Don't I need an error message to ensure that runtime behavior does not depend on the compiler used?**
No. There are two cases to consider.

*First case:* the compiler replaces `a.k` with the value `1`. The runtime behavior is the intended result.

*Second case:* the compiler does not replace `a.k` with a fixed value, instead producing some machine code that references the `a` variable. (This is what you are trying to trigger with a compiler option.) In this case, the linker sees the reference and will emit an error when the variable is not found in any of the translation units. You cannot progress to runtime behavior, so you do not get runtime results that are inconsistent with the first case.

So there could in theory be a few pains when switching compilers, but not the obscure bugs typical of undefined behavior.

In case some do not find this answer illuminating, I now return to the original question, rephrased a bit.

**Is there any flag I can use to force a diagnostic message (error or warning) when this sort of violation of the one-definition rule occurs?**
Depends on the compiler, but probably not. Note that [basic.def.odr]/10 mentions "no diagnostic required", so a compiler is not required to provide a diagnostic message when this particular violation occurs. Why not? Presumably because of the above: either a message will be triggered at a later stage (i.e. linking) or the intended behavior will shine through. There is no benefit to increasing the compiler's bookkeeping burden by requiring an error/warning in this case.

Comment: I think your answer above to a different question, not only illuminating, but brilliant. You answered all the reservations I had about the example in question.

Comment: Apparently compilers prefer the first strategy, i.e., they replace `a.k` with 1 (GCC, clang and VS do this). Given that the first strategy is UB and the second is not, why do they prefer the first option?

Comment: @JohnKalane I do not know. Perhaps the designers of the compilers disagree with the claim that the first strategy is undefined behavior? (The specs in question do not explicitly call this "undefined behavior" so there is at least room for interpretation.)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler probably won't have an option to make it fail because the compiler merely checks the language, and the language allows that.

The **linker** will have an option that makes it fail, and you can pass options to the linker through most compilers, including `g++`. I can make it fail with gcc in the following way:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Xlinker --require-defined=a main.cpp
```

which gives the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: required symbol `a' not defined
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You didn't ask for this, but `clang++` is a little easier:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -u a main.cpp
```

and more verbose, too:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "a", referenced from:
     -u command line option
     (maybe you meant: __ZNSt3__124__put_character_sequenceIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_PKS4_m, _main , __ZNSt3__111char_traitsIcE3eofEv , __ZNSt3__116__pad_and_outputIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEENS_19ostreambuf_iteratorIT_T0_EES6_PKS4_S8_S8_RNS_8ios_baseES4_ , __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_c , ___clang_call_terminate , __ZNSt3__111char_traitsIcE11eq_int_typeEii )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: But why can't the language verify the odr-use of the the variable `a` **before** the optimization is done? That's basically what I'm trying to understand. If the compiler did that an error could be emitted in this case.

Comment: This is where you need someone who knows more about C++ than I do, but I *think* it's due to the nature of C and C++: the whole point of `extern` is that it's defined in a separate linker object, possibly defined with a different language -- something elegant, perhaps, like Ada ;-) -- and C/C++ typically don't check that you cross your t's and dot your i's. For instance, you can write a function `int do_something()` that doesn't return anything, and the compiler lets it go. It's just in the nature of the language. **Keep in mind that that's my opinion only.**

Comment: Incidentally, I'm shocked that the linker let it go through. I have to put up with "undefined symbol" errors so often when working in C or C++ -- more so in the past than now, but still! -- that I actually thought the linked always checked for these things. Go figure.

Comment: I have to leave now. I'll be back in 20 minutes. Thanks for your reply and comments.

Comment: @JohnPerry: "*I'm shocked that the linker let it go through.*" Why *shouldn't* it go through? The linker probably never sees the access of `j` through `a`. Any compiler worth using will see `a.j` and immediately convert it into `A::j`, since they're conceptually *identical*. The only times it wouldn't be identical would be if `a` is not defined, which is ill-formed/NDR, so they don't have to take that possibility into account.

Comment: @NicolBolas "Any compiler worth using will see `a.j` and **immediately** convert it into `A::j`" (my emphases) . But why do they have to that before verifying the odr-use of the variable `a` in the expression `std::cout << a.k << '\n';` ?

Comment: @Ayrosa: The whole point of making ODR violations ill-formed/NDR is so that *nobody has to* verify them at all. If the committee wanted compilers/linkers to verify the ODR of all definitions, they wouldn't have made them "no diagnostic required". And in this particular case, the transformation would be done by the *compiler*, not the linker, which has no information about where `a` is actually defined.

Comment: @NicolBolas I can understand that for the case when there are more than one definition of a non-inline variable in different translation units, because that would be much harder to detect.  But that is not the case in the example above. To verify whether `a` is odr-used or not in `std::cout << a.k << '\n';` seems to me, to be straightforward.

Comment: @Ayrosa: By using `extern`, you told the compiler "assume this exists". So it is no longer up to the compiler to decide whether the object is defined; that's now the linker's job. But there's no reason for the linker to ever see `a.k` because that expression never actually accesses `a`. Whatever the standard says about that expression, the fact is that the existence of `a` is irrelevant to resolving to which object the expression accesses. And since ODR violations are NDR, the compiler can convert it to `A::k` freely.

Comment: @NicolBolas You have a point with the `extern` specifier. But in relation to "that expression never actually accesses `a`", I have to disagree. See this phrase in [\[class.static\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static#1): "in which case the object expression is evaluated".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171653/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-ayrosa).

Comment: @NicolBolas "Why shouldn't it go through?" Because the stupid linker is always complaining that it can't find some symbol that I know I compiled, no more, no less! :-) I wasn't aware there are some "loopholes," so to speak; I certainly didn't mean it in a "language lawyer" sense. I'm simply speaking from the experience of having had to figure out many times why the linker reports it can't find some symbol. I try to keep things modular, so I'm not used to using `extern` anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas "Any compiler worth using will see `a.j` and immediately convert it into `A::j`, since they're conceptually identical." I confess I don't get why they're conceptually *identical*. The first is attached to a specific field of a specific variable of structured type; the second is not attached to a specific variable. Can you explain?

Comment: @JohnPerry: Please go to the chatroom for the answer.